# convert cosine similarity to their respective strings

Tags: python, trigonometry, cosine-similarity

I am doing a clustering based on cosine similarity of many string sentences.
for example the cosine similarity of string a & string b is close to string c & string b. 
The clustering method will group them together in a list form but the values that are being group is the two cosine values.

I wish to display the actual string themselves in their grouping. But my clustering method only takes in cosine similarity values.
Any way to convert them back to their initial string?

```
MyClusters = HierarchicalClustering(List_of_cosine_values, lambda x,y: abs(x-y))
grouping = MyClusters.getlevel(0.018)
```

Comment: Are you using a library? If not, what does your cosine similarity classes look like? You need a reverse mapping - which means saving the string with the similarity and not just the similarity, currently it seems like you don't have one.

Comment: How to know what properties and methods `HierarchicalClustering` has? Usually you'd map your results back by using indices.